# What does the notation $x\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ mean?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

I have recently been reading a paper, in which mention that the parameters $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $x^1\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, so they consider $f(x^1y)$, but what does this notation in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ mean? Should I think of this as a vector of length $d+d$? or as a matrix of $d$ columns and $d$ rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^1$ is a matrix with $d$ rows and $d$ columns.

$y$ is a vector with $d$ entries.

$x^1y$ is a vector with $d$ entries and we pass it to a function $f$ which takes in a vector.

Comment: I don't know why I got so confused with the notation, thank you very much!